# Laptop takes twice the amount of time to boot when connected to an external monitor

Tags: windows-10, boot, multiple-monitors

My laptop takes 8 seconds to boot normally. Recently I had connected an external monitor, now it takes 15 seconds to start up. If I disconnect the monitor, it takes 8 seconds. So, I have identified that it is solely happening because of the external monitor. Is this the expected behavior?

System Config:

**11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz,
16.0 GB,
64-bit operating system, x64-based processor**

[image: Start Up Services Screenshot]

Is there a way I can reduce this boot time?

Comment: Windows offers a boot timing utility that will track the time each thread and process takes during the boot process. I believe it is called the Windows Performance Analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop starts with its own display and then connects to the external display.

The small additional time (a few seconds) is normal.

You may wish to try a Dock with the laptop to see if that is faster, but I would not bother. The startup is normal for this setup.

Please remember that it is the operating system via the video card driver that connects the 2nd monitor. The basic system connects the built-in monitor first.

Comment: I am already using a hub for connecting the hdmi.  Small additional time is doubling the boot time. Anything to reduce this time?

Comment: I have seen a number of these setups and your time is very normal.

Comment: Don’t forget your basic system starts your first (laptop) monitor and then your operating system starts the second monitor. It takes some extra time.